# jquery - adding new element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I set  a new property on a table element (each table should have the property selectedRow, which is a pointer to the tr element that is selected), but actually between calls of my click handler, that property becomes `null`:

```
 $("table.grid").each(function () {
        this.selectedRow = null;
    });

    var selectRow = function (tr) {

        var table = tr.parents("table").get();

        if (table.selectedRow == tr.get()) return;

        // table.selectedRow still NULL!!!!!!!!!!!
        if (table.selectedRow) {
            var unselect = $(table.selectedRow);
            unselect.removeClass('selectedChilds');
            unselect.prev('tr').removeClass('siblingUpChilds');
            unselect.next('tr').removeClass('siblingDownChilds');
        }

        table.selectedRow = tr.get();

        tr.addClass('selectedChilds');
        tr.prev('tr').addClass('siblingUpChilds');
        tr.next('tr').addClass('siblingDownChilds');

    }

    $('table.grid tr').click(function (e) {
        selectRow($(e.delegateTarget));
    });
```

Comment: are you using a plugin? Tables don't have a selectedRow property.

Comment: no i set up that property...

Comment: ok, the problem is that the property is attached to the variable that stores your table, not to the table itself.

Comment: @Christophe: but that variable is pointer to dom object, so ... it is actually set on that table i think

Comment: it doesn't, because DOM tables don't have a selectedRow property. The correct way is to set a data attribute (not a property), as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [data(key[, value])](http://api.jquery.com/data) to set/get properties:

```
$('#my-elem').data('selected_row', '...');
```